# Is using a pointer to an array element any slower than accessing the element by index?

Tags: c, performance

Let's say I have an array:

`mytype_t array[1000];`

I set up a pointer into the array:

`mytype_t * pointer = &array[317];`

Assuming `array[317]` (and surrounds) are already present in CPU cache, will dereferencing the pointer have exactly the same cost as dereferencing the array by index?

Under what circumstances, if any, would the pointer approach be slower?

**EDIT** On request of FUZxxl &Olaf, the primary architectures under consideration are Intel desktop architectures and ARM, though others are likely in the future (gaming platforms like Sony's CBEA, IBM Broadway for Wii); compiler is GCC 5.1.0.

Comment: CPU and compiler-dependent, but typically no difference in the general case. If you have a genuine performance problem then you need to benchmark/profile.

Comment: If the pointer itself needs to be loaded first, you may need an additional load compared to using the hardcoded address of the array.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the CPU cache. Why do you think that? *Any* access to that location would need to load the cache line.

Comment: The question is too broad to answer here. It not only depends on the given information, but also the whole code, how the compiler allocates registers, the compiler quality, etc. I recommend to profile the two variants and have a look at the generated code (although longer assembler code might still be faster). The outcome might change with the compiler version or CPU-microarchitecture.

Comment: @Olaf, I appreciate the heads-up. Really, I don't need a perfect answer, just a general case I can go on would be appreciated, with your caveat borne in mind. If FUZxxl's answer is sufficient in this regard, I can accept it. Otherwise I shall wait.

Comment: The answer might also depend on whether `array` is a local or a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not going to make a difference.

In the expressions `*pointer` and `array[317]`, the same address is dereferenced. Address computations are typically done in an ALU set aside just for that purpose in the CPU and don't cost much, especially (on x86) when the object size in the array is one of 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes or when the index is constant.

Furthermore, it's likely that the compiler won't actually generate `pointer` and instead decides to re-compute the address stored in it every time you dereference `pointer` as doing so saves the compiler the cost of allocating an extra register for `pointer`.

There aren't any processors I know of that speculatively prefetch data based on register contents, but there might very well be some in the future, but if that is going to be the case, the compiler is surely going to optimize your code for this.

Comment: As given by the first sentence, the answer is wrong. The answer is dependent on the CPU architecture and compiler-generated code.

Comment: @Olaf Which is why I say “typically.” Yes, you could argue that there might be exotic architectures where `*pointer` and `array[317]` do not dereference the same address, but this is clearly a question motivated from practice, not from language lawyering (which I love as you know).

Comment: You assume that I'm trying to do micro-optimisations. That's condescending. This question has nothing to do with that. It is simply something I have wondered about often in the past and so have put the question. In truth, the issue that spawned the question is one of good architecture vs. bad; I would prefer to use a pointer into a larger array, and index relative to that, than have to constantly index-by-offset into the larger array. So if I make a decision like this, it's nice to know I won't be shooting myself in the foot in performance-critical code.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I'm sorry if I sound condescending. What kind of answer did you expect? Please add some context to your question so we can understand that your question is not about micro-optimization.

Comment: They are not **that** exotic. It would be sufficient if an architecture does only have limited range for the register-indirect with offset e.g. (typical values are 8 or 12 bits), the actual code, etc. A pointer might require an additional register, chainging the rest of the code (register allocation). There are too many imponderables for just a binary answer. (Btw: such address calculations are **not** done in the ALU, but a special addressing unit)

Comment: The kind of answer that doesn't contain irrelevant cruft. The first 4 paras were fine. I really dislike when opinion rather than fact is brought into SO answers. And I need not add anything other than the barebones I have already stated in the question. The more general the question, the more useful it is as an SO resource.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: "And no, I need not add anything ..." Great attitude! You have to, if you want to get a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Olaf What part of what I've asked, is unclear? This is the question I am asking. Can either of you specify _exactly what_ you would like clarified, so I can assist your process? I cannot specify platform, because it's for a cross-platform codebase, but I can say that's gcc 5.1.0.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer You should clarify your intent. Why do you like to know this? Without an intent, your question sounds like you consider avoiding index computations as an optimization, just like most of this kind of question are motivated by trying to optimize code. And no, overly general questions are *not* useful and will be closed as *too broad.* A question that does not list important constraints cannot be answered in a satisfying way and is useless to everyone including the user who asks it.

Comment: @FUZxxl ...and a question that is too specific, like perhaps 90% of the questions on SO, are practically useless as a resource for anyone other than the OP, in the future. You tell me which is the bigger problem. :) You still have not provided any specific questions. I've already outlined in my comment above, what I'm trying to do. I appreciate your time, but mine is also valuable and I will leave it here if no specific requests for clarifications are forthcoming.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I have provided a specific question: “What is your intent?” which you did answer though, but you did not add that answer to your question. Asking a question is hard, and you are right in that a question is not useful if it is too specific. However, a question is not useful if it is too specific or too broad; it's important to hit the sweet spot inbetween. For example, a simple constraint “on common hosted platforms” would make my answer much less vague as I don't have to consider microcontrollers and exotic architectures any more.

Comment: @FUZxxl Fair points. It's hard to say re the architecture because it's an engine being built for games. So aside from Intel and ARM for now, there could be quite a few others in play like Sony's CBEA, IBM Broadway in the Wii, etc. etc., at least as time passes. So you can perhaps see why I was intentionally vague. I would not have been if I'd known this was key to answering the question. Added the details.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer All the architectures you name aren't particularly exotic in regards to address computations as far as I know. My answer should apply to them. Benchmark when in doubt.

Comment: @FUZxxl: FWIW: The edit is fine for me now. I still see not how that helps much, but OP got his pound of meat apparently;-)

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer If you're interested in details, indirect addressing *can* be slower than direct. (i.e. Stores on Haswell can use port 7 only if it's reg + fixed offset, not reg + reg, or reg + reg*scale) But you have virtually no control over that in C. Modern compilers are fully capable of converting code to and from direct/indirect addressing. Even if you know which is the faster one for a particular scenario, it's a cat-and-mouse game to get the compiler to generate one over the other.

Comment: Thanks @Mysticial. Ultimately it seems it's either a close enough call, or too difficult to determine, that it's not really worth worrying over, especially with all the platforms I need to support.